# How to begin regex search after specific character

Tags: regex, filter

I am trying to build a spam filter that only permits email addresses that end with specific top level domains.

So far this is what I got:

`.+\.(?!us|com|eu|it|de|hr|edu|gov|net|org|blog|fr|es|md|ee|bg|si|info).*$`

This issue I encounter is that this also matches email addresses that have periods prior to the @ sign.

So for example, *john.doe@gmail.com* would be blocked.

How do I apply my above regex AFTER the @ sign?

I think I need to use a look behind like this: `(<=@)`

But I'm not sure how to make the look-behind function with my above regex.

Comment: Just restrict the `.*` at the end, replace it with `[^.]*`. Or just use `\w*`, or `[a-z]*` / `[a-zA-Z]*`

Comment: My god, I was so concentrated on the start of my regex that I totally forgot about that. Wow. Thank you so much!